# Trouble using `child_process` to convert svg to png

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, svg

I inherited a Node.js project who's graph was broken.

The graph function is using `"d3": "^3.5.2"` and was just hanging on the require.

I dug around and found a problem with [contextify](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/19) and `JSDom` and then found a [solution](https://github.com/d3/d3/pull/2225#issuecomment-73426201).  It no longer hangs but it's not writing the graph correctly.

It's using `child_process` to convert from svg to png and the result is just a weird, tiny vertical line.

I've posted the code below (redacting the meat of the draw function for brevity).

If I uncomment the `For debugging` lines then the graph displays perfectly, it's losing something in the conversion.

This is all kind of new to me and I'm in a bit of a time crunch so I was hoping to see if anyone spots a glaring problem or can point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
StashModel.afterRemote('prototype.dataPointsGraph', function (ctx, unused, next) {
  var res = ctx.res,
      req = ctx.req,
      fs = require('fs'),
      StorageService = require('loopback-component-storage').StorageService,
      handler = new StorageService({provider: 'filesystem', root: res.locals.filePathRoot}),
      child_proc = require('child_process'),
      convert = child_proc.spawn("convert", ["svg:", "png:-"]);

  var d3 = require('d3'),
      jsdom = require('jsdom');

  var document = jsdom.jsdom();

  drawWaveFormGraph = function (rawData, pointFormatCb) {
    //this is a large and glorious function that successfully returns
    //the graph svg
    return d3.select(document.body).node().innerHTML;
  };

  convert.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    res.write(data);
  });

  convert.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  convert.on('exit', function (code) {
    res.end();
  });

  var fileName = res.locals.fileAbsPath;
  fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
        fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
          var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
          fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {

            var csv = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length).split('\n');
            var svg = drawWaveFormGraph(csv, function (record) {
              var fields = record.split(',');
              return {
                time: Math.floor(parseInt(fields[0], 10)/1000000),
                xAccel: parseFloat(fields[1]),
                yAccel: parseFloat(fields[2])
              };
            });

            // For debugging
            // res.write('<html><body>' + svg + '</body></html>');
            // res.end();

            res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
            convert.stdin.write(svg);
            convert.stdin.end();

            fs.close(fd);
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });

});
```

**********EDIT*************

I'm getting errors in the `convert.stderr.on('data')` function.  They are:

> convert: unable to read font `(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1315.
>
> convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3169.